# How to create apexcharts (javascript) using json local file?

Tags: javascript, json, local

As the title say, I want to create apexchart using json data that I downloaded beforehand

I already search in internet to get json data use :

> const df= require('data/processed.json');

And I already tried to call it df['liked'] as y and df['name'] as x

Is there something I miss?
Or call the column is not gonna do it?
I have also tried df.liked and df.name, btw

```
const df= require('data/processed.json');
var options = {
        chart: {
            height: 230,
            type: 'line',
            toolbar: {
                show: false,
            },
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        stroke: {
            width: 2,
            curve: 'smooth'
        },
        series: {
            name: 'Liked',
            data: df['liked']
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
        },
        xaxis: {
            type: 'string',
            data: df['name'],
            axisBorder: {
                show: false,
            },
            label: {
                style: {
                    color: '#ccc'
                }
            },
        },
        yaxis: {
            show: true,
            // min: 10,
            // max: 70,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#ccc'
                }
            }
        },
        colors: ['#73b4ff', '#59e0c5'],
        fill: {
            type: 'gradient',
            gradient: {
                shade: 'light',
                gradientToColors: ['#4099ff', '#2ed8b6'],
                shadeIntensity: 0.5,
                type: 'horizontal',
                opacityFrom: 1,
                opacityTo: 1,
                stops: [0, 100]
            },
        },
        markers: {
            size: 5,
            colors: ['#4099ff', '#2ed8b6'],
            opacity: 0.9,
            strokeWidth: 2,
            hover: {
                size: 7,
            }
        },
        grid: {
            borderColor: '#cccccc3b',
        }
    }
    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#unique-visitor-chart"), options);
    chart.render();

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
 const df = fetch("./data/processed.json")
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
```

[A documentation about fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

This way will catch all data on your json and pu it in your `const df` by using the return :)

If you want to use `require()` look about : https://requirejs.org/

**NOTE :** Try to use a lot `console.log()` to debug your js app.

Comment: Remark1: I have tried fetrch but failed eventhough the json file is in the same folder and I use fetch("processed.json"), it didn't find the file
Remark2: After trying to resolve my problems, I think my problem is when I use pipenv (virtual env in Python), it didn't read my js code. Like I can't 'require' json file. I have tried installing 'jsnode' in pipenv. But it still doesn't work...

Comment: Please, can you edit your post and show us the error log in the inspector of yout browser ? That't will help us to understand where your error is :)

Comment: Hello. There is no error wrriten anywhere. I also tried to try except console.log(error) but i didn;t get any error. In the webpage, in the location of the chart, the chart is empty even there isn't any axis x and y